# Adding text to a graphic in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following graphic:

[image]

Which is taken from the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485900/plotting-over-underfitting-graph-with-tikz-package). I would like to add some additional text to the graphic, such that, it looks something like:

[image]

To show the high bias, low bias and combination of the two -  along with the "overfitting", "underfitting" and "Good balance" labels. How can I incorporate this text into the current `tikzpicture`

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
declare function={f(\x)=0.5*pow(abs(\x-2),2)-0.06*pow(\x-2,3);}]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\Z/10}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{f(\X)+0.9*rnd}
 \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstOne{(\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{"(\X,\Y)"}
 \else
  \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne (\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{\LstTwo,"(\X,\Y)"}
 \fi}
%  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over0]
%  \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
%  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
%  \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
%  }
%  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates \LstOne;
%  \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over,xshift=-5cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Last}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Current}{{\LstTwo}[\Z]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Next}{{\LstTwo}[\Z+1]}
 %\typeout{\Last,\Current,\Next}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path ($0.6*\Current+0.2*\Last+0.2*\Next$)   coordinate 
  (p\Z);}
  \temp
  \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstThree{(p\Z)}
  \else
  \xdef\LstThree{\LstThree (p\Z)}
  \fi
  }
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth] coordinates \LstThree;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=good,xshift=-10cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth,domain=0.1:4.2,variable=\x] (\x,{f(\x)+0.45});
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=under,xshift=-15cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] (0.1,0.4) -- (4.2,2);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \foreach \X in {over,good,under}
 {\draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east);
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) node[right=1.5pt,fill=white]{Values} 
 |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east) node[below left]{Time};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add comments or text  with `\node[<options>](<name>) at (<coordinate>){<text>};` inside of `scope`. Additionally, the `TikZ` library `positioning` allows to locate nodes with respect to other nodes with *above/below,right/left* and their combinations. These can be followed by the optional arguments `<shifting part>` and `<of part>`.

For example, inside `scope`:

```
\node[red] (lowlow) at (2.2,2.5) {Low bias, low variance}; % <-- here
```

or

```
\node[red, below= -2.75cm of over] (lowlow)  {Low bias, low variance}; % <-- here
```

and then outside:

```
 \node[green,below = 3cm of lowlow] {Good balance}; % <-- here
```

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
declare function={f(\x)=0.5*pow(abs(\x-2),2)-0.06*pow(\x-2,3);}]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\Z/10}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{f(\X)+0.9*rnd}
 \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstOne{(\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{"(\X,\Y)"}
 \else
  \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne (\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{\LstTwo,"(\X,\Y)"}
 \fi}
%  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over0]
%  \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
%  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
%  \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
%  }
%  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates \LstOne;
%  \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over,xshift=-5cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Last}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Current}{{\LstTwo}[\Z]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Next}{{\LstTwo}[\Z+1]}
 %\typeout{\Last,\Current,\Next}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path ($0.6*\Current+0.2*\Last+0.2*\Next$)   coordinate 
  (p\Z);}
  \temp
  \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstThree{(p\Z)}
  \else
  \xdef\LstThree{\LstThree (p\Z)}
  \fi
  }
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth] coordinates \LstThree;
% \node[red] (lowlow) at (2.2,2.5) {Low bias, low variance}; % <-- here
  \node[red, below= -2.75cm of over] (lowlow)  {Low bias, low variance}; % <-- here
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=good,xshift=-10cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth,domain=0.1:4.2,variable=\x] (\x,{f(\x)+0.45});
%  \node[red] (highb) at (2.2,2.5) {High bias}; % <-- here
  \node[red, below= -2.75cm of good] (highb)  {High bias}; % <-- here
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=under,xshift=-15cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];
 }
 \draw[thick,blue] (0.1,0.4) -- (4.2,2);
%  \node[red] (highv) at (2.2,2.5) {High variance}; % <-- here
  \node[red, below= -2.75cm of under] (highv)  {High variance}; % <-- here
 \end{scope}
 %
 \foreach \X in {over,good,under}
 {\draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east);
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) node[right=1.5pt,fill=white]{Values} 
 |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east) node[below left]{Time};}
 \node[green,below = 3cm of lowlow] {Good balance}; % <-- here
 \node[green,below = 3cm of highb]  {underfitting}; % <-- here
 \node[green,below = 3cm of highv]  {overfitting}; % <-- here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```